# how to edit the link user/%/edit?

Tags: users, path-aliases, routes

i have a test user called "buyer".
he has a profil with the tabs: view - edit - orders - files
i set pathauto for user to: user/[user:name]
when i look at the tab links the as followed:

view: domain/user/buyer
edit: domain/user/82/edit

question: why is that?
if i call the link domain/user/buyer/edit by hand, i get
"You are not authorized to access this page."

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because path aliases are for a single path, so the path alias user/[user:name] is only for user/82.
If you want path aliases for all those other pages, they have to be added separately.

And because they are not pages that are covered by the pathauto module, you cannot use it for those pages.

You can manually add aliases at admin/config/search/path/add but because you can't use tokens there you would have to add aliases manually for each user (which is ridiculous).

The only module I know that can help you out is http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto

The equivalent module for drupal 6 is http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias

Those modules aim to allow you to do what you desire.

It seems there is currently a bug in the subpathauto module though that is breaking user aliases. See http://drupal.org/node/1851102

I just tested 7.x-1.2 and it is working correctly.

You can get 1.2 from here - http://drupal.org/node/1416736

Comment: ok thank you rooby, i have had installed subpathauto once but after a closer look the links now as i wish:

edit: domain/user/buyer/edit

one problem remains, as i click or type the url i get "Access denied" 
is this common?

Comment: What is the domain part you are adding at the start? Do you mean yoursite.com/domain/user/buyer/edit or yoursite.com/user/buyer/edit ?
 - If the former, why are you adding domain?

Comment: i mean yoursite.com/user/buyer/edit

Comment: Just tried it myself with subpathauto and it seems to work sometimes but sometimes I get access denied. Strange.

Comment: ok i see.
this is what i found on that topic, in the bug list there is something about that behaviour:
http://drupal.org/project/issues/subpathauto?status=All&categories=bug

Comment: Haha, I just found the same one. I tried version 7.x-1.2 and it works.

Comment: nice one! i also looking for the 1.2 version but i dont know were to get it. do you have a link for me pls?
...found :D so we helped each other i would say:D

Comment: additional info:
lines 25-28 has to be removed in v1.3
seems that makes the difference

Comment: Is this similar to my own Question? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70703/what-is-the-correct-uid-path-whilst-using-ubercart-affiliate-in-custom-db

Comment: I added a link to 7.x-1.2 in the answer.
You can also get to it via the "View all releases" link on the project page. Or if you are using drush it is drush dl subpathauto-7.x-1.2