# What is the Correct UID path whilst using Ubercart Affiliate in Custom DB

Tags: ubercart, uri

I'm currently building a various user dashboard using my own custom hacked Workbench (WB) & cloned from one Master for end users (3 roles ex SU). WB chosen over Homebox as that was taking me too long and WB seems easier to integrate Views etc. FYI, I'm working on a D7.2x local Linux Ubuntu webdev box using the system localhost.

Things are going well and general path links to modules link well (Support tickets, Messages etc). However, one of the options I'm offering is the Ubercart Affiliate and whilst that module is working fine, I cannot for the life of me get a users Affiliate account path to show up correctly via a direct link from the Workbench. I require the path to be simply: site/user/affiliate linking direct the Affiliate dashboard (DB).

For my benefit, for now I created Custom Content Pane (as opposed to a Block) and simply created HTML links into it as one would do (using 'other' as the option URL settings. The other links work fine linking to the relevant modules, but the link to users main Affiliate DB overview won't work. I set "Affiliate Center" as the link to the UC Affiliate DB but am I either confused over the correct path structure or something is missing or both.

For example, user' joetest' can login and is redirected on login to his WB and all shows aok. joetest can access his UC DB via: [http://localhost/sitename/user/12/affiliate] but what I presumed was correct (...sitename/user/%/affiliate) or .../user/uid/affiliate) neither don't work and gives me an error message of what I expect, "affilate shop not found etc...".

I know it's a path issue (Redirect, Pathauto, URL-Alias) but I cannot figure it out. I checked all permissions and others.

I'm quite happy for the end result to be:  in order for the user to access their said UC Affiliate main 'home' DB even maybe using the [ME](http://drupal.org/project/me) module? I'm not sure.

Presume this should be a five minute setup, but a few hours later, I'm getting stumped now but simply want to user to be able to view, edit, amend their Affilate details but via either a link on their WB. Not looking to use Menu tabs as I'm wanting a very light, minimal structure.

Any advice great appreciated.

Ok, I'm a learning 'novice', but probably missing a small point on the path structure knowledge. (:
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using the [ME Alias module](http://drupal.org/project/me) which allow the insertion of the said UID into the path I required for all users.